# UnauthorizedAccessException: writing to SQL Server filestream

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Database where I enabled the FILESTREAM for Transact-SQL access and file I/O access. The drive `sqlexpress2019 (\\ComputerName)(Z:)` is accessible in the explorer.

When trying to create a directory `SqlScripts` to the FILESTREAM, like so:

```cs
DirectoryPath = "\\\\ComputerName\\SQLEXPRESS2019\\FW_fsc\\SqlScripts";
Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryPath);
```

I get the following error:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path '\\ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS2019\FW_fsc\SqlScripts' is denied.'`

If I try to create the directory by hand in the explorer, I get the following error:

`You need permission to perform this action`

What are the steps that must be taken to be able to write to the FILESTREAM?

Comment: SQL Server files are automatically put in the machine "Program Files" folder (\\ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS2019) that a Admin account is need to write.  So you need to put the files in a folder the users have permission or use an Admin account to write the files.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jdweng said, I do not have the permission to write in the folder.

In SQL Server, in `DBName -> Tables -> FileTables` I created the table `SQL_SqlScripts` like so:

```sql
USE [DBName]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SQL_SqlScripts]******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SQL_SqlScripts] AS FILETABLE ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FW_FilesGrp]
WITH
(
FILETABLE_DIRECTORY = N'SqlScripts', FILETABLE_COLLATE_FILENAME = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
GO
```

This created the `SqlScripts` folder in the FILESTREAM where I have the required permissions to write.